# Angular - $http Scope Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently working with Angular and have an issue with `$http`. A couple of my controllers use `$http` just file, applying the results to `$scope.variable` however on my current controller I'm having an issue.

```js
app.factory('getUserData', function($http) {
  var user = [],
    url = 'res/asp/manageaccount.asp?action=',
    custid = getCookie('custid');

  return {
    getUserInfo: function() {
      url += 'getUserInfo&custid=' + custid;
      return $http.get(url);
    },
    getShipInfo: function(callback) {
      url += 'getShipInfo&custid=' + custid;
      return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
        user = response.data;
        return user;
      });
    }
  };
});

app.controller('accountController', ['$scope', 'getUserData',
  function($scope, getUserData) {
    $scope.custid = getCookie('custid');
    getUserData.getUserInfo().then(function(data) {
      $scope.userInfo = data.data;
      console.log($scope.userInfo); // Logs the array with the object data I need
    });
    // Accessing $scope.userInfo here is 'undefined'
  }
]);
```

I've tried two different ways to return the data. The data returns fine however I cannot access it in my page - only within the scope of defining `$scope.userInfo`. Getting the data isn't the issue it is displaying it on the page.

```html
<div class="container" ng-controller="accountController">
  
  <h1>Welcome Back, {{userInfo.fname}}!</h1> <!-- Doesn't work -->
  
  <div class="row" ng-controller="cartController">
    <!-- This works fine -->  
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    {{userInfo.fname}} <!-- Doesn't work -->
    {{custID}} <!-- Works -->
  </div>
  
</div>
```

### TL;DR

`$http` returns data but cannot access it with `{{userInfo.fname}}` in my page.
I've looked a lot of SO questions/answers and this one seems to be the most [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28655195/angular-http-returns-data-but-doesnt-apply-to-scope).

Comment: what does `console.log(data);` output?

Comment: @Ronnie `Object {data: Array[1], status: 200, headers: function, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}` and `data.data` output `[Object]` which contains the data I need.

Comment: seems to be an array, what if you try access `{{obj[0].prop}}`?  Or  `scope.userInfo = data.data[0]`

Comment: what does console.log(data[0]); output?

Comment: `{{obj.prop}}` was just a placeholder. I'm actually using `{{userInfo.fname}}` to try and write out to the page. Logging `$scope.userInfo` returns the object properly but can ONLY be done while inside the `getUserData.getUserInfo()` declaration.

Comment: @aarosil `{{userInfo[0].fname}}` worked. So I just need to set `$scope.userInfo = data.data[0]` then..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the answer you are looking for. You should rename `.then(data)` to `.then(response)` to avoid confusion. `response.data[0]` should be the object

```
app.controller('accountController', ['$scope', 'getUserData', function($scope, getUserData)
{
  $scope.custid = getCookie('custid');
  getUserData.getUserInfo().then(function(response)
  {
    $scope.userInfo = response.data[0];
  });
}]);
```