# http returns data but doesn't update view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this input field in my html:

```
    <input  type="text" spellcheck="false" id="widgetu1049_input" 
    name="custom_U1049" tabindex="3" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="searchText"
    ng-change="getPostHttp()" ng-trim="false"/>
```

and i'm calling http post in a scope function:

```
    $scope.getPageItems = function(callback){//TODO add county and state moudles

    var search = {'searchText':$scope.searchText,'state' : $scope.currentState,'county' : ''};
    var params = {'action':'getPageItems', 'currentPage':$scope.currentPage, 'pageSize':$scope.pageSize, 'search':search };


    $http.post(EndPoint, params).then(function(response) {

        var page=response.data;
        console.log(page);
        callback(page);
    });

}
```

I'm calling the above function from this function:

```
$scope.getPostHttp = function(){
    $scope.getPageItems(function(data) {
        $scope.items = data;
    });
}
```

I've got this approach from this question [Angular $http returns data but doesn't apply to scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28655195/angular-http-returns-data-but-doesnt-apply-to-scope)

And although it shows the items on an ng-init call I made, it does not update on the ng-change call above.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I'm adding the view of the ng-repeat call:

```
<tr style=" background-color: #BFBFBF;" ng-model="items" ng-class="{marked: isExists(item.id) == true}" ng-click="view(item.id)"
 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#smallModal" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-animate="'animate'">
   <td ng-show="id">{{item.id}}</td>
   <td ng-show="fname">{{item.fname}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If you log `data`, do you get what you requested? You may have to use `$scope.apply()`

Comment: I do get the data, but It doesn't let me use `apply` (probably because it's already in an `apply`).

Comment: @JeremyJackson There is absolutely no need to use `$scope.apply()`. It is only used when angular is to be notified of the changes outside it's scope. And I am pretty much sure that is not the case here.

Comment: can you try removing ng-model from <tr>? try to use only with ng-repeat

Comment: I removed the `ng-model="items"` ,but it didn't help.

Comment: Removed my answer, since it is not possible that `$scope.items` is being updated, as you mentioned yourself, while it is not being updated in the html.

Comment: Also, it would help if you posted the code inside your `ng-repeat`

Comment: what's that `ng-show`
 in the `td`'s?

Comment: shouldn't that be `ng-show="item.id"` and `ng-show="item.fname"`?

Comment: I believe @lascort is right

Comment: Those are boolean options of the columns.
I meant elaborate on your first comment

Comment: I know, but you're checking some `$scope` variable `id` and `fname` which are not defined, so I'm guessing you actually meant what my comment above says. Try removing the `ng-show` altogether and see if that works

Comment: Apparently the problem was with the ng-init, I removed it and now it's updating. Thanks!